# ¿Cómo mostrar formato dd-MM-yyyy en un JTable?

Tags: java, mysql, date, jtable

Tengo este pequeño código que me trae datos de una base de datos a un 'JTable', quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de que el campo 'date' lo muestre en formato 'dd-MM-yyyy':

```
private void cargarTabla() {

ResultSet rs = Vista.getTabla("SELECT codigo, fechanaci FROM alumnos");
model.setColumnIdentifiers(new Object[]{"Codigo", "FechaNaci"});
try {
    while (rs.next()) {
        model.addRow(new Object[]{rs.getString("codigo"), rs.getDate("fechanaci")});
    }
    jtblRegistro.setModel(model);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, e.toString());
}
```

}

[image: Algo como esto]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba incluyendo 'SimpleDateFormat' para dar el formato que tú deseas y luego pasárselo a través del 'value'. Dejo aquí un ejemplo modificando tu código ligeramente:

```
  private void cargarTabla() {
    SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");

   ResultSet rs = Vista.getTabla("SELECT codigo, fechanaci FROM alumnos"); model.setColumnIdentifiers(new Object[]{"Codigo", "FechaNaci"});
    try {
        while (rs.next()) {
           model.addRow(new Object[]{rs.getString("codigo"), rs.getDate("fechanaci")});
           if( value instanceof Date) {
                value = f.format(value);
           }
      }
     jtblRegistro.setModel(model);
   } catch (SQLException e) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, e.toString());
   }
  }
```

Dejo aquí un enlace a la documentación de dónde se ha extraído la información para la respuesta y que es posible que resulta de ayuda para está u otro dudas con tu proyecto: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer